# Serving on http://127.0.0.1:8000: WinError 10013: Port is used by other process

Tags: python-sphinx

Error when trying to get documentation page:

```
[I 230831 20:02:57 server:335] Serving on http://127.0.0.1:8000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\rfnei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\sphinx-autobuild.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\rfnei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sphinx_autobuild\cli.py", line 194, in main
    server.serve(port=portn, host=args.host, root=outdir, open_url_delay=args.delay)
  File "C:\Users\rfnei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\livereload\server.py", line 339, in serve
    self.application(
  File "C:\Users\rfnei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\livereload\server.py", line 291, in application
    app.listen(port, address=host)
  File "C:\Users\rfnei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 2134, in listen
    server.listen(
  File "C:\Users\rfnei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tornado\tcpserver.py", line 183, in listen
    sockets = bind_sockets(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\rfnei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tornado\netutil.py", line 162, in bind_sockets
    sock.bind(sockaddr)
PermissionError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a method prohibited by access rights
```

Port user:

```
F:\Blender_build\blender-manual>netstat -o -n -a | findstr 8000
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4552
  TCP    [::]:8000              [::]:0                 LISTENING       4552
```

Name of this user:

```
httpd.exe                     4552 Services                   0     4 836 KB
```

I'm really not sure if I can kill this port user.

Can I provide a anothr one port id for the documentation server to avoid this conflict?

I want to start documentation server/page without any conflicts and follow-up issues.
I tried to explore possible solutions, checked the startup flags. but did not find information to bypass the problem.

```
Please use `make target' where target is one of
  html        to make standalone HTML files
  dirhtml     to make HTML files named index.html in directories
  singlehtml  to make a single large HTML file
  pickle      to make pickle files
  json        to make JSON files
  htmlhelp    to make HTML files and an HTML help project
  qthelp      to make HTML files and a qthelp project
  devhelp     to make HTML files and a Devhelp project
  epub        to make an epub
  latex       to make LaTeX files, you can set PAPER=a4 or PAPER=letter
  text        to make text files
  man         to make manual pages
  texinfo     to make Texinfo files
  gettext     to make PO message catalogs
  changes     to make an overview of all changed/added/deprecated items
  xml         to make Docutils-native XML files
  pseudoxml   to make pseudoxml-XML files for display purposes
  linkcheck   to check all external links for integrity
  doctest     to run all doctests embedded in the documentation (if enabled)
  coverage    to run coverage check of the documentation (if enabled)
  clean       to remove everything in the build directory
```

Start command/

```
set SOURCEDIR=.\manual
set BUILDDIR=build
if "%BF_LANG%" == "" set BF_LANG=en
set SPHINXOPTS=-j auto -D language=%BF_LANG%
    sphinx-autobuild --open-browser --delay 0 "%SOURCEDIR%" "%BUILDDIR%\html" %SPHINXOPTS% %O%
```

Comment: sphinx-autobuild has a `--port` option: https://github.com/executablebooks/sphinx-autobuild#command-line-options.

Comment: Yes, I was blind and simply did not check the repository of this program! (I trusted the list of flags that was printed by the used bash wrapper...) Can you answer the question to close it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by using the `--port` option of sphinx-autobuild.

```
sphinx-autobuild --port 8999 --open-browser --delay 0 "%SOURCEDIR%" "%BUILDDIR%\html" %SPHINXOPTS% %O%
```

See https://github.com/executablebooks/sphinx-autobuild#command-line-options.